# How can I make android beep 3 times?

Tags: java, android

How can I make android beep 3 times one after the other.
I am currently using a tone generator.
Is there a way to make it beep 3 times or do I have to use something like a Timer?

Comment: Running the function 3 times. I thought it might queue 3 beeps but it played all 3 at the same time.

Comment: Show us the possible code or show us what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a similar issue while working on a project, I found that this assisted me tremendously: [Beeping in Android (Custom Sound)](http://www.androidsnippets.com/beep-by-intent)

Taking into consideration what they describe to you there, you can simply utilize a for loop, and execute the "playAudio" function 3 times in order to get it to beep 3 times.

If you do not wish to go look at it there, refer to code snippet from that website, below:

---

```js
package com.example.test;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PicturesBeep extends Activity 
{
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
         for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            playAudio();
         }
    }

    private void playAudio () {
        try {
                // http://www.soundjay.com/beep-sounds-1.html lots of free beeps here
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep9);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            Log.e("beep","started0");
            mMediaPlayer.start();
 //           Log.e("beep","started1");
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                       finish();
                }
        });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("beep", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Notice the for loop that will run the function 3 times, thus playing the sound 3 times.

I hope this helps you.

Please let me know of the outcome.

Comment: This seems to use the MediaPlayer class which I believe uses a resource sound file you pack yourself.
I am currently doing
startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ALERT_CALL_GUARD, 200);
which uses android default beep.
It looks like the mediaplayer class automatically spaces out the sound clips.

Comment: Yes, is that not what you were looking for? As I understand if you played the sounds 3 times, it would run 3 times concurrently instead of one at a time?

Comment: @FrickenHamster ... So did this assist you?

Comment: I just ended up using a timer. I guess I could have used this but used the default tone instead of a media file. Thanks anyways

Comment: Please mark correct if I assisted or pointed you in the right direction.